# SH execution from Java GUI application don't work

Tags: java, bash, sh

I'm trying to execute a SH script from my java GUI application. I'm using jsch to connect to the machine.
I can execute commands like "`ls`" or "`pwd`". When I try to execute my SH I only get all output from it, if I execute it directly in the machine it take several time (that's what is expected) and works fine.

The script begins with

> "#!/bin/bash"

and the code that call it is:

```
String command=  "cd /opt/app/ordersync/scripts/RE-INJEC;sh ./proc_reinjec.sh"; // enter any command you need to execute  
         Channel channel=session.openChannel("exec");
         ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(command);
        channel.setInputStream(null);
         ((ChannelExec)channel).setErrStream(System.err);
         in = channel.getInputStream();
         channel.connect();
```

When I execute it

> I get TERM environment variable not set

I can't figure it out what is the problem. I tried to the same in php with `shell_exec` and I the problem (result) was the same.

Comment: What commands does your shell contains ? I suppose there's one that needs TERM environment  variable ... Maybe you could try to set `TERM` to `xterm` or `vt100` or `dumb` via `ChannelExec.setEnv`

Comment: I'm trying to execute this command: `rm *.csv` in the script, after it I get the TERM error.

Comment: @FabioCardoso I would try something less dangerous ;) `touch beacon` Or more informative like `pwd` or `ps` if you you can see the output of your commands

Comment: @SylvainLeroux it's a isolated folder, no problem about that command, anyway is not that the problem. I tried `nohup` writing to a log and it seems work, what is weird.

Comment: Have you tried to execute your script by using `ssh` on the command line? Try to issue some commands remotely like `ps`, `set` or `setenv`, `pwd` in order to have a better understanding of the host environment when connected to the remote machine. Please show the result of those various commands in your question. Maybe they will contain some clue? You might have something unusual with you SSH configuration. Maybe...

Answer (score 0):

This is only a *guess*. So consider that mostly as a (long) comment. But you are assuming your "command" will in fact be parsed by an intermediate *shell*, that might even be responsible to set a proper environment. But, does `ChannelExec` really launch a shell? Or does it instead execute directly the command?

Anyway, try that:

```
String command=  "sh -l -c 'cd /opt/app/ordersync/scripts/RE-INJEC;sh ./proc_reinjec.sh'";
//                ^^^^^^^^^^                                                           ^
//                  explicit sub-shell       don't forget the closing quote >-->-->----/
//                  '-l' is for login shell: reads /etc/profile, ... at startup
//                                           I don't know if this is required here
```

But maybe in fact you are searching for [ChannelShell](http://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelShell.html) instead?

---

From [RFC 4254, section 6.5. Starting a Shell or a Command](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4254#section-6.5):

> 6.5. Starting a Shell or a Command
>
> Once the session has been set up, a program is started at the
> remote    end.  The program can be a shell, an application program, or
> a    subsystem with a host-independent name.  Only one of these
> requests    can succeed per channel.
>
> ```
>   byte      SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_REQUEST
>   uint32    recipient channel
>   string    "shell"
>   boolean   want reply
> ```
>
> This message will request that the **user's default shell** (typically
> defined in /etc/passwd in UNIX systems) be started at the other end.
>
> ```
>   byte      SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_REQUEST
>   uint32    recipient channel
>   string    **"exec"**
>   boolean   want reply
>   string    command
> ```
>
> This message will request that the server start the **execution of
> the    given command**.  The 'command' string may contain a path.
> Normal    precautions MUST be taken to prevent the execution of
> unauthorized    commands.